# Binding Error on Unix platform

Tags: unix, bind

I get binding error for ftp server in Unix:server.sin_port = 8000; //atoi(argv[1]);

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
k = bind(sock1,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
if(k == -1){

   printf("Binding error\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

I checked the port using netstat, looks the port is free...

```
netstat -an | 8000 grep
```

Comment: Maybe you can get the value of `errno` as described in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Unix man pages are your best buddy in such cases.  Bind man page indicates as shown below.

> #### RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

**So, to find out what's the actual bind error you should print out the error message associated with errno, soon after you do bind syscal.  perror() is solely used for this change the code to as shown below.  You'll find the reason for failure.**

```
   #define print_error_and_exit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

   server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
   k = bind(sock1,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
   if(k == -1)
       print_error_and_exit("bind");

   /* Continue with the flow */
```

Comment: It says:

bind: Address family not supported by protocol

tried two differrent port:

  server.sin_port = 1125; //atoi(argv[1]);
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
  k = bind(sock1,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response..  The error is because you are trying to find to ip address 0... Try this....

#define print_error_and_exit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_port = htons(2058);

k = bind(sock1,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
if(k == -1)
print_error_and_exit("bind");

/* Continue with the flow */